# Web View Android App on opening upon installing says " App Stopped working"

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am a Rookie in Android Studio. I thought of making my PHP website to a webview app through android studio by following a tutorial.

I did exactly what it said, but unfortunately, my app says "App stopped" upon opening after installing.

I changed only three files of code, activity_main.xml, Android Manifest, MainActivity.java.

My code goes as:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <webview
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </webview>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Android Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.telanganaprajafront.www.tpf">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/screen"
        android:label="Telangana Praja Front"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/screen"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.telanganaprajafront.www.tpf;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.telanganaprajafront.com/forapp/index.php");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    // Use When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.centerend.com")) {

                return false;

            }


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

At the begining of the project start, i choosed the "blank activity" in the screen selection.

When i Build APK the log cat - Event log says like:

```
1:30 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

1:36 PM Gradle build finished in 5m 10s 538ms

1:36 PM Build APK(s)
    APK(s) generated successfully:
    Module 'app': locate or analyze the APK.
```

Please let me know if i did any mistake in the code.

Comment: you might be getting some error in logcat..paste that error...

Comment: Is _webview_ typo mistake? Because it must be  _WebView_. Also post logcat

Comment: no, when i build signed apk, it gave no error in logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: You mean when you signing your apk  at that moment you are getting an error?

Comment: no, I generated an signed APK and it is installing in my mobile but when i open an installed app, i says "Stopped Working"

Comment: @SonySomeya can you try implementing this http://codesfor.in/android-webview-example/ (simple webview implemenation)

Answer (score 1):

After long review, I found my Answer,

I forgot to write the website name at

`if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.centerend.com")) {`

and convert the webview to WebView  at activity_main.xml  (Thanks @Piyush)

Comment: and another thing, when i open my app, and click on internal pages, it open a chrome browser instead of opening INapp....can you help me on this one

Comment: Because you have written your code  `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

            startActivity(intent);` which will redirect to browser.

Comment: how to change it

Comment: You want to open same page in webView? Then just comment that line code

Comment: yeah, i mean, when i click a link in that app, it should not redirect to a external browser

Comment: Do you think writing this `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` willl do the work

Comment: Yes it should be ! Check [this](https://www.androidauthority.com/working-with-webview-736873/)